# How to Pass a Query String to Google Sheets API v4 in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-visualization, google-sheets-api

In the previous version I used to do(simplified):

```
 var queryString = encodeURIComponent('SELECT A,B,D,C WHERE D=1');
 var query = new google.visualization.Query(
          'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1*SPREADSHEETID*/gviz/tq?gid=1013479342&headers=1&tqx=responseHandler:handleQueryResponse' + '&access_token=' + encodeURIComponent(gapi.auth.getToken().access_token));
 query.send(handleQueryResponse);

 function handleQueryResponse(response) {
 var dataTable = response.getDataTable();
 }
```

Now, to take advantage of Google Sheets API v4 (gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get) which doesn't work in v3. I do:

```
      var params = {
    valueRenderOption: "UNFORMATTED_VALUE",
    spreadsheetId: '*YOURSPREADSHEETID',
    range: 'Sheet1!A:D', 
      var request = gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get(params); 
  request.then(function(response) {
         var values = response.result.values.map(function(e) {return [e[0], e[1], e[3], e[2]]});
    var w = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({dataTable: values, 
    query: "select * where D = 1"}); // THIS DOESN'T WORK
   var dataTable = w.getDataTable();
```

I thought I can just add "query: "select * where D = 1" " in the chartwrapper properties in an attempt to avoid to sort and go through each element in the array or use an additional controlwrapper.

Answer (score 2):

I'll leave this here. After further research, Google Sheets API v4 still doesn't support simple filtering.

One of the devs at Google thinks filtering should be an exclusive feature for a full-fledged database and google sheets ain't one so I doubt they'll ever bring back the feature from v3.

If you need filtering you have 3 options:

- filter your spreadsheet first (make multiple worksheets with the filtered data and then call the range that already has the filter applied).
- go back to using Google Sheets v3 which does support filtering (see above).
- filter the data after you receive it at the client level(yes I know that's the worst for performance).

I choose to go with the third method. Since I'm working with Google Visualization API, all I had to do is apply a filter on the dataview before I draw it.

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(dataTable);
view.setRows(dataTable.getFilteredRows([{column: 4, value: 1}]));
```